# Display PDF file in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to display a PDF file in WPF. I have done it but after some time its stops working. Please help me below is my code:

```
else if (result.FileExtension == ".pdf")
{
    // TODO: Make sure you point to a PDF on your system:
    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(result.ImageToByte);
    var uc = new UserControl1(str);
    this.windowsFormsHost1.Child = uc;
}
```

Below is my UserControl code:

```
public UserControl1(string filename)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.axAcroPDF1.LoadFile(filename);
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Margin="1" Name="windowsFormsHost1" />
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Are you getting errors and/or exceptions?

Comment: could be some compatibility issue with `axAcroPDF1`.better to ask the vendor.

Comment: define "stopped working".  we can't troubleshoot something without knowing the symptoms

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar in one of my projects.  In the end I use a WebBrowser to host the PDF document.  Obviously this means that the users will need PDF viewer installed on their machine but that was a small price to pay.

One problem I did have was with 64bit machines.  I had target x86 mmachines in order for the PDF to show up on a 64bit machine.

In XAML:

```
<WebBrowser visual:WebBrowserExtensions.BindableSource="{Binding Path=Model.AnnouncementUrl, ElementName=Root}"/>
```

WebbrowserExtensions:

```
public static class WebBrowserExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindableSourceProperty =
         DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindableSource", typeof(object), typeof(WebBrowserExtensions), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, BindableSourcePropertyChanged));

    public static object GetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(BindableSourceProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindableSource(DependencyObject obj, object value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindableSourceProperty, value);
    }

    public static void BindableSourcePropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebBrowser browser = o as WebBrowser;

        if (browser == null)
            return;

        Uri uri = null;

        if (e.NewValue is string)
        {
            var uriString = e.NewValue as string;
            uri = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uriString) ? null : new Uri(uriString);
        }
        else if (e.NewValue is Uri)
        {
            uri = e.NewValue as Uri;
        }
        browser.Source = uri;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works fine, but if pdf-file size is large - application will be suspended :(

Answer (score 0):

I worked with the axAcroPDF1 control a while ago, and I did have problems when loading large PDF files.

So, instead of using LoadFile, try the following:

this.axAcroPDF1.src = filename;